# Кнопка поделиться картинкой

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!

Можно ли с андроид-приложения поделиться картинкой, например в ВК или еще где нибудь. Обычный текст отправляется без проблем, но с картинкой не могу разобраться. Можно ли вообще это сделать?

При нажатии на кнопку получаю из БД адрес картинки (использую sugar) и пытаюсь ее отправить с помощью share.

В приложении картинка отображается, но не могу отправить.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Contact img = Contact.findById(Contact.class, idInt);
// получаю из БД адрес картинки
    int photoId = img.photoId;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.fab:
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoId);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Что представляет из себя адрес картинки (переменная `photoId`)?

Comment: Да это значение не имеет, можно вместо неё добавить прямой адрес, все равно не выходит

Comment: А картинка где хранится?

Comment: R.drawable.bolshrastmsl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде разобрался

```
                Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                    + "/drawable/" + "bolshrastmsl");
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
            break;
```